# Open new code in web browser?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way I can use an anchor tag `<a>` or JavaScript code to open a new website but instead using a url as input it opens a custom code input?

Comment: yes. there is. on windows you could initiate opening a website in the default browser by using the windows script host

Comment: Yes. Websites are made up of code. Using code you can make a website appear in a web browser.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking how to open a new page that renders HTML from a string instead of a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Read the test from a text box, like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value2

Then call.
window.open(URL)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="http://www.google.com">

<p>Click the button open window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open(document.getElementById("myText").value)
    //Bravo";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

format your url like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:alert('hello!');">Click here</a>
```

Hovever, this is a JS inject and most websites, including SO filter it out